# Where can I watch the latest Pokemon Season 18 episodes subbed?

Tags: pokemon

Seaon 18 refers to the XY: Kalos Quest. Subtitles should be in English. It can also be English dubbed. I have tried [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/) but most of the episodes are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you're in the US, you can watch them on [Amazon Videos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WJ3K8F8) or from the [iTunes Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/tv-season/pokemon-series-xy-kalos-quest/id1016675284?i=1016734846&ign-mpt=uo%3D5)

Comment: I want watch them for free.I am not from US.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you're from, we do not answer questions "requesting illegal copyrighted and/or licensed materials". If you have a question about Pokemon we would be happy to answer, though.